# Read tag NFC ID from foreground dispatch

Tags: android, nfc

I am trying to read an NFC tag ID. I know I wont be able to read the data as it is a secure tag (MBTA Fare card). I would like to read the tags unique ID and toast that value. I have successfully gotten the NFC intent to work, so that when a tag is scanned my app attempts to handle it. However app does not show the toast with the tag id.

```
    package com.example.nfctest;

import android.nfc.NdefMessage;
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.nfc.tech.NfcF;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.IntentFilter.MalformedMimeTypeException;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     private NfcAdapter mAdapter;
        private PendingIntent mPendingIntent;
        private IntentFilter[] mFilters;
        private String[][] mTechLists;
        private int mCount = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);

        // Create a generic PendingIntent that will be deliver to this activity. The NFC stack
        // will fill in the intent with the details of the discovered tag before delivering to
        // this activity.
        mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);

    // Setup an intent filter for all MIME based dispatches



    IntentFilter ndef = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
    try {
        ndef.addDataType("*/*");
    } catch (MalformedMimeTypeException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("fail", e);
    }
    mFilters = new IntentFilter[] {

    };

    // Setup a tech list for all NfcF tags
    mTechLists = new String[][] { new String[] { NfcF.class.getName() } };
}
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, mPendingIntent, mFilters, mTechLists);

}

@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    Log.i("Foreground dispatch", "Discovered tag with intent: " + intent);
    CharSequence text = ("Discovered tag " + ++mCount + " with intent: " + intent);
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

    Tag myTag = (Tag) intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);


    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,myTag.getId().toString() , duration);
    toast.show();
}


@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    //mAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
    throw new RuntimeException("onPause not implemented to fix build");
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

It no longer crashes, just doesn't do the toast with the ID.

Comment: can you post the exception you get from logcat?

Comment: [link](http://pastebin.com/0XVA2L6f) Was too long to paste in.

Comment: This should give you a clue: Didn't find class "com.example.nfctest.nfc.TechFilter"

Comment: Wow, that honestly slipped by, I have since fixed that. Its not crashing anymore but it isnt giving me the toast with the ID.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend this [this sample application](http://nfc.android.com/StickyNotes.zip) in [this link](http://www.jessechen.net/blog/how-to-nfc-on-the-android-platform/). Don't give yourself pain by trying everything to succeed easy operations, as I did.

You probably doing something wrong in placements of operations in onResume and onNewIntent. However, in the example I linked you, it has controls for new tag and ndef in both onResume and onNewIntent. If you really want to go on your own project, try this.

Comment: The sample does work, however it does well more then I need it to. I just need something that scans a tag, gets its unique ID and executes some code based on it. And its for a class, so I can't really just use that, I have to learn it to a degree.

Comment: Writing is more complex than removal, I guess. Open the project in debug mode and watch the process step by step, you'll discover easily what you should remove. That's what I did :)